# How do I pass multiple variables to a function in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to compare a column from several pairs of `pandas` dataframes and write the shared values to an empty list. I have written a function that can do this with a single pair of dataframes, but I cannot seem to scale it up.

```
   def parser(dataframe1,dataframe2,emptylist):
        for i1 in dataframe1['POS']:
            for i2 in dataframe2['POS']:
                if i1 == i2:
                    emptylist.append(i1)
```

Where `'POS'` is a column header in the two `pandas` dataframes.

I have made a list of variable names for each input value of this function, eg.

```
dataframe1_names=['name1','name2',etc...]
dataframe2_names=['name1','name2',etc...]
emptylist_names=['name1','name2',etc...]
```

Where each element of the list is a string containing the name of a variable (either a pandas dataframe in the case of the first two, or an empty list in the case of the last).

I have tried to iterate through these lists using the following code:

```
import itertools

for a, b, c in zip(range(len(dataframe1_names)), range(len(dataframe2_names)), range(len(emptylist_names))):
    parser(dataframe1_names[a],dataframe2_names[b],emptylist_names[c])
```

But this returns `TypeError: string indices must be integers`.

I believe that this error is coming from passing the function a string containing the variable name instead of the variable name itself. Is there another way to pass multiple variables to a function in an automated way?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you *have* to use strings of object names, instead of just the objects themselves? If you do

```
dataframes1=[name1,name2,...]
dataframes2=[name1,name2,...]
emptylists=[name1,name2,...]
```

Then you can just do

```
for a,b,c in zip( dataframes1, dataframes2, emptylists ):
    parser(a,b,c)
```

The way you do this is really circuitous and unpythonic, by the way, so I've changed it a bit. Rather than getting lists of indexes for the for statement, I just iterate through the lists (and thus the objects) themselves. This is much more compact, and easier to understand. For that matter, do you have a need to input the empty list as an argument (eg, perhaps they aren't always empty)? And your code for the parser, while correct, doesn't take advantage of pandas at all, and will be very slow: to compare columns, you can simply do `dataframe1['COL'] == dataframe2['COL']`, which will give you a boolean series of where values are equal. Then you can use this for indexing a dataframe, to get the shared values. It comes out as a dataframe or series, but it's easy enough to convert to a list. Thus, your parser function can be reduced to the following, if you don't need to create the "empty list" elsewhere first:

```
def parser( df1, df2 ):
    return list( df1['COL'][ df1['COL']==df2['COL'] ] )
```

This will be much, much faster, though as it returns the list, you'll have to do something with it, so in your case, you'd do something like:

```
sharedlists = [ parser(a,b) for a,b in zip( dataframes1, dataframes2 ) ]
```

If you *must* use variable names, the following *very unsafe* sort of code will convert your lists of names into lists of objects (you'll need to do this for each list):

```
dataframes1 = [ eval(name) for name in dataframe1_names ]
```

If this is just for numerical work you're doing in an interpreter, `eval` is alright, but for any code you're releasing, it's very insecure: it will evaluate whatever code is in the string passed into it, thus allowing arbitrary code execution.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a use case of .[query](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#query-use-cases)()

> A use case for query() is when you have a collection of DataFrame
>   objects that have a subset of column names (or index levels/names) in
>   common. You can pass the same query to both frames without having to
>   specify which frame you’re interested in querying

```
map(lambda frame: frame.query(expr), [df, df2])
```

Answer (score 0):

What kind of output are you looking for in the case where you have more than two `DataFrame` objects? In the case of just two, the following line would accomplish what your `parser` function does:

```
common = df1[df1["fieldname"] == df2["fieldname"]]["fieldname"]
```

except that `common` would be a `DataFrame` object itself, rather than a list, but you can easily get a list from it by doing `list(common)`.

If you're looking for a function that takes any number of DataFrames and returns a list of common values in some field for each pair, you could do something like this:

```
from itertools import combinations
def common_lists(field, *dfs):
    return [df1[df1[field] == df2[field]][field] for df1, df2 in combinations(dfs, 2)]
```

The same deal about getting a list from a DataFrame applies here, since you'll be getting a list of DataFrames.

As far as this bit:

```
import itertools

for a, b, c in zip(range(len(dataframe1_names)), range(len(dataframe2_names)), range(len(emptylist_names))):
    parser(dataframe1_names[a],dataframe2_names[b],emptylist_names[c])
```

What you're doing is creating a list that looks something like this:

```
[(0,0,0), (1,1,1), ... (n,n,n)]
```

where `n` is the length of the shortest of `dataframe1_names`, `dataframe2_names`, and `emptylist_names`. So on the first iteration of the loop, you have `a == b == c == 0`, and you're using these values to index into your arrays of data frame variable names, so you're calling `parser("name1", "name1", "name1")`, passing it strings instead of pandas `DataFrame` objects. Your parser function is expecting `DataFrame` objects so it barfs when you try to call `dataframe1["POS"]` where `dataframe1` is the string `"name1"`.